# How Do I Import A Xades Signed Xml Document Into Another Xml Document?

Tags: c#, xml-signature

I am trying to import a signed xml document into another xml document. When i import the document, and export it with no change, i can no longer validate it.

Even the code below breaks the validation.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.ShowDialog();

if (ofd.FileName != "")
{
   XmlDocument XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   XmlDocument.Load(ofd.FileName);

   FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
   fbd.ShowDialog();

   if (fbd.SelectedPath != "")
   {
      XmlDocument.Save(fbd.SelectedPath + @"\Doc.xml");
   }
}
```

How can i import/export an xml document without breaking the signature validation?

My Xml Files are:

- Envelope : [dl.omerharmansa.com/envelope.xml](http://dl.omerharmansa.com/envelope.xml)
- Invoice : [dl.omerharmansa.com/invoice.xml](http://dl.omerharmansa.com/invoice.xml)

invoice.xml is the document that is signed. I want to import invoice.xml into envelope.xml. The element of envelope.xml, which invoice.xml is going to imported, is shown.

Comment: How your signed XML (and your merged document) look like?
Because you have to set the correct Reference for the signature. If you don't set it correctly, the validation will try to create the hash for the entire merged XML.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following signed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MySignedXMLRoot xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MySignedXMLNode>TextToBeSigned</MySignedXMLNode>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>3tAjL2X1SEMhxQ1Hp9X4HBUtsgQ=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>UYyELdlqq1InZSwSKozhIuATU52gdVFw0AqnZxOB0xQR6CS2hbW5tZIXc6fMPSYstyfMVULO1ZioRkHvyIY7LqeR/i4cYZvA1VpzTnx+0gZEcPFEuMORNgJ0v/W7NHi5xJb6uxkdZBcSMleFWitTHO+tPh8tha0cNdp4XO8Xx4Y=</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</MySignedXMLRoot>
```

If you want to include it in the following XML document:

```
<MyXML>
    <SomeData>Random Data</SomeData>
    <Container/>
</MyXML>
```

You have to correctly set the Reference attribute of the signature:

```
<MyXML>
    <SomeData>Random Data</SomeData>
    <Container>
        <MySignedXMLRoot id="ElementToSign" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <MySignedXMLNode>TextToBeSigned</MySignedXMLNode>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#ElementToSign">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>3tAjL2X1SEMhxQ1Hp9X4HBUtsgQ=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>UYyELdlqq1InZSwSKozhIuATU52gdVFw0AqnZxOB0xQR6CS2hbW5tZIXc6fMPSYstyfMVULO1ZioRkHvyIY7LqeR/i4cYZvA1VpzTnx+0gZEcPFEuMORNgJ0v/W7NHi5xJb6uxkdZBcSMleFWitTHO+tPh8tha0cNdp4XO8Xx4Y=</SignatureValue>
            </Signature>
        </MySignedXMLRoot>
    </Container>
</MyXML>
```

You can set it with [Reference.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.reference.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Let's forget about the import part. Consider the given code in my question, when I load a signed xml document from my computer and save it into a new location, the signature breaks down. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Could you share your XML file with us?